# How to connect to an SQL Server 2016 instance from windows 7?

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2016

We're migrating from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016. I need to connect to an SQL Server 2016 instance from my PC in windows 7. In this PC, there're :

- SQL Server Manager Studio, installed from an ISO file of SQL Server 2012 Entreprise Edition
- ISO file of SQL Server 2016 Developer edition

With the current SSMS, I can connect to SQL Server 2012 instances, but I can't connect to the new SQL Server 2016 instance. And when I try to re-install the SSMS from the ISO 2016, it failed saying that my PC windows 7 is not compatible :

> The operation system on this computer or its service pack level does not
>   meet the minimum requirements for SQL Server 2016. To determine the minimum
>   required operating systel supported for this SQL Server release, see Hardware
>   and Software Requirements for installing SQL Server 2016 at :
>
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398123

My questions are :

- Is it possible to connect to SQL Server 2016 from Windows 7 ?
- If possible, what is the requirement for the SQL Server Manager Studio, do I need to install any update ?

I don't need the SQL Server instance running on my PC. The client side SSMS is enough.

Comment: "I can't connect to the new SQL Server 2016 instance" - what happens when you try?

Comment: It is possible to run SSMS on Windows 7 and connect to a SQL Sever 2016 instance, but it is not possible to run a SQL Server 2016 instance on Windows 7.  The link that you provided shows that the standard version's lowest operating system is Windows 8.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx shows the requirements for SSMS allowing Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks @Phritzy, your reply is exactly what I need. This newest version of SSMS will probably resolve my problem. Could you provide it as an answer, so that I can accept it tomorrow, once I return to my company and make every work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poviding this as an answer instead of comment.

It is possible to run SSMS on Windows 7 and connect to a SQL Sever 2016 instance, but it is not possible to run a SQL Server 2016 instance on Windows 7. The [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398123) that you provided in the error message shows that the standard version's lowest operating system option is Windows 8. [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) shows the requirements for SSMS allowing Windows 7 (SP1).

Comment: The error was the SQL Server 2016 didn't enble the protocols _TCP/IP_ and _Named pipes_ during the installation. And once enabled, SSMS 2012 can connect to instance SQL Server 2016, without installing SSMS 2016. But your answser is constructive.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS is now supported independent of the SQL installation.  As of v16, it is maintained independently and claims backwards compatibility to SQL2008.  The latest version is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

As of this post, SSMS v17.9.1 worked on my installation of Windows 7 Pro x64 and allowed me to connect to a remote SQL2017 instance.

SSMS version 17.x or later does not support connecting to the legacy SQL Server Integration Services service. To connect to an earlier version of the legacy Integration Services, use the version of SSMS aligned with the version of SQL Server.